# white space in between div elements

Tags: html, css, whitespace, margins

I've looked at a bunch of similar questions for this problem and I still can't seem to figure out the solution (still just learning all of this stufF).

I'm trying to make a portfolio website and I've placed each project inside a div element (not sure what I'm doing with the divs...). I'm having trouble removing the large amount of white space in between the divs/projects which are shown vertically, so you have to scroll down to see the next one. I've tried adjusting the margins to 0 on p, h3, and the divs with no luck. Any ideas?

```css
body,
html {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h3 {
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

li {
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: normal;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: normal;
}

div.movie {
  transform: scale(0.5);
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 1200px;
  padding: 25px;
  float: left;
  clear: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  display: block;
}

div.reader {
  transform: scale(0.5);
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 30px;
  float: left;
  clear: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  display: block;
}

.main .projects {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

div.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  padding-top: 35px;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 40%;
  padding-top: 2%;
}

p {
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <h3> olivia schneider, </h3>
    <h3> graphic designer & writer </h3>
    <br>
    <h3> +1 (585) 766 5189 </h3>
    <h3> olivia.schneider@vcfa.edu </h3>
    <h3> instagram </h3>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <!-- <h3> recent projects </h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li> Hunger Mountain #25</li>
                    </ul> -->
  </div>
  <div class="projects">
    <div class="movie"> <video width="1200" height="800" src="/Users/oliviaschneider/Documents/code projects/PERSONAL WEBSITE_small victories/resources/American Healthcare_OSchneider_PinUp2020 copy.mp4" controls autoplay muted> </video>
      <p>2020 — typography, creative direction, video editing</p>
      <p>American Healthcare</p>
      <p>A short movie I made after I turned 26, got kicked off my parent's healthcare plan, and waited 5 hours to sign up for my state's healthcare coverage.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="reader"> <video width="1200" height="800" src="/Users/oliviaschneider/Documents/code projects/PERSONAL WEBSITE_small victories/reader copy.mp4" controls autoplay muted> </video>
      <p>2020 — web design, front-end development, writing </p>
      <p>A Web Reader</p>
      <p>A place for my essays, reflections, and critiques of things. </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How did you make your html page?  Is it from a template or framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite of the `transform: scale(0.5);` setting, those divs still occupy their original space, i.e. their original position and size *without*  that transform.

So you probably better erase that setting and adjust the size of the included video, either in absolute measures (as I did below, using the inline attributes) or by using `width: 100% and` height: auto`on the`video` elements.

(note: I erased the sidebar from the code in the snippet below to concentrate on the actual problem you described)

```css
body,
html {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h3 {
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

li {
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: normal;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: normal;
}

div.movie {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 1200px;
  padding: 25px;
  float: left;
  clear: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  display: block;
}

div.reader {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 30px;
  float: left;
  clear: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  display: block;
}

.main .projects {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

div.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  padding-top: 35px;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 40%;
  padding-top: 2%;
}

p {
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">

  <div class="projects">
    <div class="movie"> <video width="600" height="400" src="/Users/oliviaschneider/Documents/code projects/PERSONAL WEBSITE_small victories/resources/American Healthcare_OSchneider_PinUp2020 copy.mp4" controls autoplay muted> </video>
      <p>2020 — typography, creative direction, video editing</p>
      <p>American Healthcare</p>
      <p>A short movie I made after I turned 26, got kicked off my parent's healthcare plan, and waited 5 hours to sign up for my state's healthcare coverage.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="reader"> <video width="600" height="400" src="/Users/oliviaschneider/Documents/code projects/PERSONAL WEBSITE_small victories/reader copy.mp4" controls autoplay muted> </video>
      <p>2020 — web design, front-end development, writing </p>
      <p>A Web Reader</p>
      <p>A place for my essays, reflections, and critiques of things. </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you!!!!!! I'll keep going by looking at your example here.